# Using external type definitions with some types not exported

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet

I am using typescript in ReactJs together with Leaflet library (for displaying world maps). I needed to provide the typescript definitions for the library, but they already exist, so I installed them as a node module under @types.

In some place the library requires type of:

```
(feature: Feature<Geometry, any>, layer: Layer) => void
```

so I thought it will not be a problem, I created such function:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
...
function f(feature: L.Feature<L.Geometry, any>, layer: L.Layer){}
```

the `Layer` type works without any problems, but for `Feature` or `Geometry` I get:

```
Namespace '"/.../node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no exported member 'Feature'
```

so I checked what is inside the type definition file:

```
export as namespace L;
import * as geojson from 'geojson';
...
onEachFeature?(feature: geojson.Feature<geojson.GeometryObject, P>, layer: Layer): void;
```

it's hidden under `geojson`, but when I try to access it, like `L.geojson.Feature` I get `has no exported member named 'geojson'`, so I changed my own code to:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import * as geojson from 'geojson';
...
(feature: geojson.Feature<geojson.Geometry, any>, layer: L.Layer
```

and it works but I am confused, because I thought you don't import type definitions, but only your code and the types living in x.d.ts will be imported for you (this is how the type `L.Layer` works). However, there is no `geojson` module in the main `node_modules`, it's nested under @types module. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It looks more like the library author did something wrong in not exposing the types required to interact with the library properly. Or maybe you missed it in the documentation? If they do indeed refer to the same type, then your solution seems good. If you run into issues later for any reason I would deal with that hurdle when it comes up.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that many times it's no the actual author of the library who delivers the type definitions. They write it in vanilla js, and someone else takes on the job of writing matching type definitions. So there is always a chance that the type definitions are not the best or incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought you don't import type definitions

Actually we do, it is just that TypeScript does it automatically for us with the actual import:

```
import L from 'leaflet'; // Bundler will import the Leaflet library,
// while TypeScript will look for types in the library, or in "@types"
```

There are several `tsconfig` [modules options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Modules_6244) to configure this automatic behaviour, like `types`, `typeRoots` (by default the `@types` folder) and `paths` (for aliases).

As you figured out, it is also possible to import just types. You can use `import type` to make it explicit (and to hint the bundler that there is no code to actually import):

```
import type * as geojson from 'geojson';
```

It is also possible to access non exported types by deep access:

```
type TonEachFeature = L.GeoJSONOptions["onEachFeature"];
//   ^? ((feature: geojson.Feature<geojson.GeometryObject, any>, layer: Layer): void) | undefined

// You can type the function and let TS infer the argument types automatically
const myOnEachFeature: TonEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
    feature
    // ^? geojson.Feature<geojson.GeometryObject, any>
    layer
    // ^? L.Layer
}
```

And using [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html):

```
function myOnEachFeature2(feature: Parameters<NonNullable<TonEachFeature>>[0], layer: L.Layer) {
    feature
    // ^? geojson.Feature<geojson.GeometryObject, any>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAGTgMyhEcDkAbApgQ2TxkwG4AoUSWOGATzFzgCo58BnOAc1wgCt2EAHYo0GTD36ChZcuQAUyAjACuUXAC5uvAcIB0AMWVrcAHkm6hegOK8QuGFDoAaNkLoA+V9nx1cULQQ9BF9-AEo4AF4POABvOABfOXpGOAAVYQBRfABjAAsjfFV1KMQbXgApAGUAeQA5GrAYYGF2AG0AIizcguN1DoBdCgB6YbhxgD0Afjkc1vgQOhqhbPzC4s107rW+pki4RV3vUKgI6LjycfGlIpNLq9G4afvxnz8oF7hH56TyZBUhDlmsI4Itlqterd1AAmQ5QzYABXwUHw9hg-nYpjqwjqKmwPgARnhTBkVj11iYPB42gAGAbHd6BYInCKxT43Dafb4zJJAA)